# Parse string date (EEST included) but it fails

Tags: c#, .net, date, datetime, format

I am trying to parse a string into a `DateTime`, but it fails and shows an exception. The code is provided below:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string dt = "Wed Sep 05 00:00:00 EEST 2012";
    string Fm = "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy";
    DateTime dateTime;

    dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dt, Fm, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    Console.WriteLine(dateTime.Date);
}
```

This is the exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
   at System.DateTime.ParseExact(String s, String format, IFormatProvider provider)
   at DateParser.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\AhmedSaeed\source\repos\DateParser\DateParser\Program.cs:line 17
```

Comment: Ahmed, here's the page with all format specifiers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings?view=netframework-4.7.2#the-zzz-custom-format-specifier

Comment: By coincidence, I was using http://csharpexamples.com/c-string-formatting-datetime/ just moments ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=netframework-4.7.2) structure does *not* keep time zone information. It just have date and time values which is based a long called [`Ticks`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.ticks?view=netframework-4.7.2). That's why there is no [custom date and time format string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) that matches that abbreviation. The [`zzz` format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#the-zzz-custom-format-specifier) is for the signed offset of the local operating system's time zone from UTC and it is *not* meaninful to use it with `DateTime` parsing as stated on the documentation.

If you wanna parse an abbreviation in your string, you have to escape it as a string literal. Other than this, there is no way to parse it. On the other hand, timezone abbreviations are not even unique. For example, CST can mean Central Standard Time, China Standard Time or Cuba Standard Time.

Also there is no `EEE` custom date format specifier. Abbreviated day names matches with [`ddd` format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#the-ddd-custom-format-specifier) instead.

```
string dt = "Wed Sep 05 00:00:00 EEST 2012";
string Fm = "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss 'EEST' yyyy";

DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dt, Fm, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Console.WriteLine(dateTime.Date);
```

Here a [`demonstration`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/btK9uw).

Comment: @AhmedSaid Glad to help.

Answer (score 3):

> string dt = "Wed Sep 05 00:00:00 EEST 2012";

Although a real timezone, "EEST" does not match the `zzz` format (in length) and this may be an issue.

Additionally, as apomene said, `EEE` is not a valid format string.