# How can I convert to valid DateTimeUtc this string` "2020-05-25 15:25:40 EEST"?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a date time value as below and I want to convert it to date time UTC in C#.

```
var dateTime = "2020-05-25 15:25:40 EEST";
```

I tried DateTime.ParseExact and DateTime.TryParse, but I am getting below error:

> System.FormatException: 'String '2020-05-25 15:25:40 EEST' was not
>   recognized as a valid DateTime.'

I need to have output something like this ` 2020-02-24 12:09:42.103.

Comment: If you're able to, could you not do some string manipulation and remove the EEST before you try convert it to a DateTime?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One way of converting the date format is to `escape` 'EEST' timezone information!

You can find the details in another question, [`Parse string date (EEST included) but it fails`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55283540/parse-string-date-eest-included-but-it-fails).

In your case the following code will help:

```
var dateTime = "2020-05-25 15:25:40.123 EEST";
string format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff 'EEST'";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTime, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Console.WriteLine(dt.ToUniversalTime());
```